# search bar and segmented control

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I add UISegmentedControl on storyboard and add SearchBar in code:

```
searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
discountTableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

Invalid position of Search Bar after its activation. 
How fix it?
[Before clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5409S.png),
[After clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXXIc.png)

Comment: Did you setup constraints?

Comment: @AhmadF Yes. On segmented control under bar. constraints: top,left,right and height. and TableView under segmented control top,botton,left,right.

Comment: I found the solution this problem. Need set searchBarStyle = .minimal. Maybe have another solution?

Answer (score 0):

I overcame this by implementing delegate method of `UISearchController`

```
- (void)willPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {

    if (searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles.count == 0) {
        //somewhere I got this
        // there is an Apple bug when first time configuring search bar scope buttons
        // will be displayed no matter what with minimal searchbar
        // to fix this adding scope buttons right before user activates search bar
        searchController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = NO;
        searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = @[@"title 1", @"title 2"];
    }

}
```

Hope it will help you too.

Comment: I can't use ScopeBar. I need always to show SegmentedControl.